# How to interpret this date value?

Tags: delicious-api

HI,

When I am importing my delicious bookmarks to a html file, the date when the bookmarks get added comes as a attribute ADD_DATE. The values for it are like 1265772027, 1265767184 etc.. How do I convert these values to actual date and time??? I am at a loss at interpreting these.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seconds since epoch (1970-01-01)

so in SQL Server You would do (add 1265772027 seconds to 1970-01-01)

```
select DATEADD(ss,1265772027,'19700101')
```

and the result is 2010-02-10 03:20:27.000

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).

> Unix Timestamp 1265772027
>   Wed, 10 Feb 2010 03:20:27 GMT

Answer (score 0):

Maybe misunderstanding but... Are you using some language or are you manually going to do this?

PHP:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i',your_time);
```

Javascript:

```
var date = new Date(your_time*1000); // Milliseconds
```

etc.